# Proximity of colors in a rainbow

Tags: python

I got n points which belong to a rainbow (or are close to being a "rainbow color"). Now given a point which is also a rainbow color, I want to find the **closest match** out of the n points.

What is a robust and simple data structure + algorithm combination to do this? Using (R,G,B) tuples and Eularian distances came to my mind.

Yes, I got a serious use case :-)

Comment: Do you mean [Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)? Other than that, your suggestion sounds like a pretty good solution - choose RGB values for your rainbow colours as targets, then use (R,G,B) as coordinates and measure the distance between your given colour and the target colours. You could also look at other distance metrics - [the See Also section for Euclidian distance on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#See_also) has some examples.

Comment: You should probably convert all your colors to LAB and do the distance calculations because it is more perceptually uniform than RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not playing around with rainbows ;-) but I have almost the same situation and I use a kd-tree for this to quickly search the closest "point". My points are also rgb colors in the form of 0-1 floats

http://code.google.com/p/python-kdtree/

```
from kdtree import KDTree

data = [(1,2,3),(4,0,1),(5,3,1),(10,5,4),(9,8,9),(4,2,4)]

tree = KDTree.construct_from_data(data)
nearest = tree.query(query_point=(5,4,3), t=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mostly right, but HSL or HSV will probably allow for a bit more accuracy in that you can weight the attributes. See [`colorsys`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably convert your RGB values to [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) where matching color proximity based on hue should be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You said *rainbow colours*, which in the usual sense means monochromatic colours in the visible spectrum, i.e. colours of single frequency (white or pink are not rainbow colours). In such a case, you have the great advantage of being able to represent them with just their frequency or wavelength, a single number. Have a look here for example to see the frequencies corresponding to a sample division of the rainbow spectrum:

- http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/primcol.htm

So now you have *n* numbers, and then you pick another number (another rainbow colour) and have to decide which of these it is closest to. Which should be trivial.

So if you have your rainbow colours in terms of their frequency (which you should, otherwise how do you know they are rainbow colours?), it's a simple job.